# requirejs optimizer named module bug

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, requirejs, amd

I want to define a module, that does nothing but require other modules, to make sure they are included. like this:

````
File: common.js
define(['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route']);```
````

r.js output is:

```
define(['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route']);
```

this is wrong because it is supposed to output a named module.

However if i define it with a dummy function callback like this:

```
File common.js
define(['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route'], function() {});
```

r.js outputs properly.

```
define('routes/common',['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route'], 
      function() {});
```

Is it okay to define a module with a sole purpose of requiring other modules like this?

And why does r.js behave like this?

**Edit**

I am having trouble with the amd lingo so i will define my problem.

I have a router.js which includes all the modules.

```
File: router.js
define(['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route', 'routes/other_route'], 
       function() {

       });
```

I include all these `routes` ('index_route, guides_route'), but i don't really need any references. So instead of including a bunch of
`routes` inside router.js like this, i want to include all these `routes` in a seperate file, and include just that file inside router.js.

```
File: router.js 
define(['routes/common'], function() {});

File: routes/common.js
define(['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route', 'routes/other_route']);
```

Then the above problem arises.

**TL;DR** I think you are confusing what require and define is. and what r.js is used for.

I though the difference between `require(['module'], function() {})` and `define(['module'], function() {})` is
require function is immediately called, define function is called only when its required by some other module.

So
`if you want to request modules you need to use require insead of define` makes no sense.

**TL;DR** Just tell me the difference between:

```
define(['module']);
define(['module'], function() {})
```

In terms of how optimizer operates on them. That will tell me why optimizer outputs differently in two cases.

```
define(['module']);
define('filename', ['module']);
```

If i am in some kind of pitfall please shed more light please otherwise don't confuse me further with noise.

Comment: When you say "this is wrong because it is supposed to output a named module.", why does that matter? Are you saying that ```define(['routes/common'], function() {});``` is not working when the optimizer doesn't name the module to ```routes/common```?

Comment: @sahbeewah When optimizer doesn't name the module, it cannot find `routes/common` module in the browser and gives an error. It doesn't work if i omit the `function() {}`, otherwise it names the module properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand your question correctly, using 'packages' property of require.config will help you,

Keep your common file as it is, i.e.

```
File common.js
define(['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route'], function() {});
```

Like,

```
options: {
    paths: ...,
    packages: [{
        name: 'routes/common', // or 'routes' or anything
        location: 'routes',
        main: 'common'
    }],
    ....
}
```

Then you can directly use that name of module to in your 'router.js' file.

I do this to create a single named module for multiple files, including which load all sub-modules in main file of package.

Edit:

You can also omit the 'name' property of package if you want. In that case you can rename 'common.js' to 'main.js' since it is a standard name for entry point of packages. So, renaming 'common.js' to 'main.js' it can become,

```
options: {
    paths: ...,
    packages: ['routes'],
    ....
}
```

Refer following URL for more explanation/options,

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages

Comment: If i don't use `packages` config, and require `define(['routes/common'], function() {});` like this, it should load all the dependencies inside `routes/common` anyway, i don't understand why i have to use extra config for that?

Comment: The advantage is more apparent when you rename the file to `main.js` and it also defines the purpose of using that main file. By looking at your require configuration, you can tell that `routes` folder might have some JS files being used by it internally, but for the application the whole folder acts as a single entity (i.e. a package).

And btw, you can also use the `require([]);` syntax in that main file, if defining an empty function is not what you want.

Comment: Do you have a real world example, i am unclear what goes into `main.js` file, and how that differs from not having a `packages` config. Also this won't still answer my original question, that is, if this is a optimizer bug, or i am getting something wrong?

Comment: What you are facing is not a optmizer bug. Logically, define is used to 'define' a module. If you are not returning anything (including implicit return of undefined if you do not use return statement), there is no module defined. So, optimizer thinks that if there is nothing coming out, there is nothing to be named! And in this case it will not generate a named module! But in case of require, there is no requirement of returning anything, so it works there.

Answer (score 1):

r.js behaves properly. If you want to request modules you need to use `require` instead `define`

```
require(['routes/index_route', 'routes/guides_route']);
```